# tomcat catalina log rotation using shell script

Tags: shell, solaris

I am rotating `catalina` logs using `cron job` and `shell script`.

Below is the code snippet being used in log rotation

1. Backup existing `catalina.out` into other file

   `cp -p $ORI_LOG_PATH $NEW_LOG_PATH`
2. flush existing `catalina.out` file

   `cp /dev/null > $ORI_LOG_PATH`

Now the problem is, some of the time (point to be noted NOT ALWAYS) can see some junk characters(`NULL,NULL,NULL....`) on top of the rotated log.
What could caused this?

I am using `Solaris 10`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the tomcat startup script using a `#!/bin/sh` shebang. On Solaris, this is the original, non POSIX Bourne shell.

In that startup script, `catalina.out` is written using the `>>` redirection.

With modern shells `>>` is implemented using the O_APPEND flag but with the legacy Bourne shell it is implemented by seeking to the end of file before writing.

The side effect is if you blank the file while it is open, the `catalina.out` file is turned to a sparse file with virtual NULLs at the beginning.

The workaround is simple, replace the shebangs in the tomcat `*.sh` scripts by something like:

```
#!/usr/xpg4/bin/sh
```

or

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: jlliagre thank you for the response.                               I am using #!/usr/bin/ksh only.

Comment: I'm not talking about your scripts but the ones delivered with tomcat.

Comment: Let me fix in this way and test for couple of days. Thanks you Jilliagre

Comment: Ok, beware that you should shutdown then startup tomcat for the shebang change to be taken into account !